# How to prevent those sudden ugly popups in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

How do I stop those ugly in-your-face popups in html5 from showing? (Most ask for sign up to their newsletters)

I installed Pop-up Blocker which seemed to work for most sites but did not for PCMag.com.

So many sites now exhibit this idiocy as soon as the page loads. If they have it when they detect an exit from the page I don't mind but not as soon as it loads !

Comment: have you used ADB Plus?

Comment: @GiannisTzagarakis I believe you should be using Ublock Origin right now, instead of ADB Plus.

Comment: I m fine with ADB, not a single popup is up

Comment: No, I was using AdBlock, guess I will now give the other one a whirl ..thanks !

Comment: @Piwwoli's suggestion worked great, and page loads much faster too..if you can paste this as an answer in the SU link I will mark it as BA.

Comment: I cannot do that, at least not right now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't, because they are not popups in the browser sense. The site authors utilize tools like div containers and javascript/jquery to cause these ads to show up. The best you can do is either not patronize the site, or contact them and request that the annoying banners be removed. (That's what I do.) Unfortunately since it's not a pop-up, the only other option is to disable scripting/javascript, which would likely cause the site to no longer function.

Comment: thanks, I moved the question over to SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/1013766/how-to-prevent-those-sudden-ugly-popups-in-chrome